# CakePHP 2.0, the return data of model's function 

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

I use cakephp2.0, in one server, cakephp return the data from Database , like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [users] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 1
                    [username] => admin
                    [password] => 90c4c3e64eb085da3a9feccc38489281
                    [admin_role] => 24
                    [datetime_reg_time] => 
                    [datetime_last_login] => 2012-04-24 15:15:55
                    [email] => 
                )

            [roles] => Array(...)
```

but another server return the data is :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [user_id] => 1
                    [username] => admin
                    [password] => 90c4c3e64eb085da3a9feccc38489281
                    [admin_role] => 24
                    [datetime_reg_time] => 
                    [datetime_last_login] => 2012-04-23 11:41:35
                    [email] => 
                    [roleId] => 24
                    [roleName] => 管理员
                    [rolePermissions] => 60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,93,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,109,112,108,107
                )

        )
```

I don't kown why.....
Is't PDO's version ?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered like you asked

this is cakephp's bug

because your other server pdo not support **PDOStatement::getColumnMeta()**。

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.getcolumnmeta.php

Answer (score 0):

It's php's problem, When I install php , I should config like this: ./Configure ....--with-pdo-mysql=mysqlnd